# Помощь с реккурсией

Tags: java, рекурсия

Для функции

```
static int num(int x){

        switch(x){

        case 0: return 1;

        case 1: return 3;

        default: return num(x-1)+2*num(x-2);}

}
```

вызов `num(n)` вернул 11. Чему равно значение n, для которого осуществлялся вызов? равно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чем проблема проверить:

```
    public class AppTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("i " + i + " - " + num(i));
            }
        }

        public static int num(int x) {
            switch (x) {
                case 0:
                    return 1;
                case 1:
                    return 3;
                default:
                    return num(x - 1) + 2 * num(x - 2);
            }

        }
    }
```

Вывод:
i 0 - 1
i 1 - 3
i 2 - 5
i 3 - 11
i 4 - 21
i 5 - 43
i 6 - 85
i 7 - 171
i 8 - 341
i 9 - 683